# Auto resize Textview

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

My goal is to create Auto rotate textView.Here is my xml code

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/u_major_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="0.00"

                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12dp"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="70dp"
                android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="70dp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/u_minor_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/u_major_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/u_major_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/u_major_text"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="₾"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

my goal is to my minor_textview can to be auto resize function.first time text size is 70dp but I want to decrease size depends on a text. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: follow this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: Please explain more @BekaKK why you need to do this?

Comment: for example if text is 0.00 -text size should be 70 dp ,but if text is "000000000000" texts size must decrease automatically

Comment: you should have to create a function as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, since Android 8.0 and below (thanks to the Support Library) you can use an attribute to auto resize your Textview:

```
TextView minorText = findViewById(R.id.u_minor_text);
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(text, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
```

Check this link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview